# CSS Flexbox: filling blank space between vertical elements

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a problem with flexbox:
I have the HTML:

```
<div class="panel-body">
   <div class="project">

   </div>

   <div class="project">

   </div>
   <div class="project">

   </div>
   <div class="project">

   </div>
   <div class="project">

   </div>
 </div>
```

You probably get the idea...

Now, I want it to look like this:

|project| |project| |Project|

|project| |project| |Project|

|project| |project| |Project|

etc..

But, some projects are taller than others. So about a year ago I managed to put them nicely with isotope.js plugin, like this:

[image: Isotope can do that pretty simply]

As you can see, the item "5555" is right after "Nexus 5", and the same about "44444" and "Nexus 7".

The question is, How can I do that with flexbox? Is that possible?

My current CSS code:

```
.panel-body{
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   align-items: flex-start;
}

.panel-body .project {
   flex-grow: 1;
   flex-shrink: 1;
   flex-basis: 300px;
   margin: 1px 10px;
}
```

and this is how it looks right now(the arrows tell you how I want it to look)

[image: Flexbox Problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with `flex-box` yet. But, CSS3 `columns` may provide you with something close to what you are after.

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/nHbdL/***

*HTML Markup*:

Same as in your question.

*CSS*:

```
div.panel-body { 
    height: 600px;        /* fixed height allows you to control column fill */
    -webkit-columns: 3;   /* number of columns that you want */
    column-count: 3;      /* the standard property after all prefixed ones */
}

div.project {
    background-color: #cfffbd;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; /* will prevent breaking blocks across columns */
    column-break-inside: avoid;         /* the standard property after all prefixed ones */
}
```

.

Comment: Thanks you @abhitalks ! Is that supported only in -webkit browsers? Should I use it **instead** of Flexbox?

Comment: @ReuvenKarasik: For other browsers, just add the vendor prefixes like "-moz" etc. Make sure the standard one comes last. AFAIK, flex won't solve your problem.

Comment: Downvoter - any particular reason of down-voting this after 2 years?!?! A comment would be appreciated.